# Using Wordpress Custom Field Check Boxes in Template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have created a meta box in Wordpress which contains custom fields including check boxes. I am unsure as to how to check which check box has been selected from within my template.

**Custom Fields**

```
array(
                "name"          => "offer-type",
                "title"         => "Type of offer",
                "description"   => "Please select what kind of offer this is",
                "options"       =>  array( "TYPE A","TYPE B"),
                "type"          => "checkbox",
                "scope"         =>  array( "post" ),
                "capability"    => "edit_posts"
),
```

**And my template loop**

```
    foreach ($posts as $day => $post) {

    // 2 LINES BELOW ARE RELATED TO QUESTION
    $offer_types = unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_mcf_offer-type", true));


    echo var_dump($offer_types);
```

My var dump is returning a "false" boolean, whereas it should be returning the value of selected checkbox. Is there something wrong with the implementation?

Comment: I REALLY hate to say this and I'm not going to be the one to report the question (there will be dozens of others who will though). There is a custom WP SE site at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which this would be better asked in. Also, the wordpress and ACF forums would also be a great place to look. To the question itself, where did the `_mcf_` come from? Also, checkbox should only be `true` or `false`, shouldn't it? Otherwise test for `TYPE A` or `TYPE B`

Comment: also, my first google search brought up the following link: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/ 
are you using any plugins?

Comment: I know there is Wordpress Stack Exchange, however I do find there is a lot more knowledge shared on SO.

Should I be using 'select' or 'radio' inputs?

Comment: I cannot use AFC unfortunately otherwise this would never of been asked. The site I am working on is stuck on WP V3 so cannot use ACF

Comment: I concur, which is why I don't downvote. I've just been amazed at the number of closed questions I coming across today as being off topic, but answer my question exactly

Comment: Not seen any problems with asking WP related question on SO, also if I was to ask on WE now it would be flagged as duplicate question..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94907/discussion-between-madivad-and-james).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our extended discussions, try calling the post via `$post('post_id')`

I don't think you need the `unserialize` either.

Your whole line would become:

```
$offer_types = get_post_meta($post['post_id'], "_mcf_offer-type", true);
```

Comment: Excellent discussion and knowledge sharing, thanks bud